# Google Calendar Event GUI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api

does anybody know, where I can find the Google Calendars Event-GUI?

I'm building an social networking site, which relies on google calendar.
For adding and changing events, I want to use googles GUI (i dont want to code this myself if there is a partial/control already existing).

Does anybody know where I can find this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/ it's the full API documentation from Google. If what you want to do is supported, it's almost certainly written about here somewhere.

If you take a look at the [docs](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/docs/2.0/developers_guide.html) page, there is a "Calendar Tools" section on the left hand side bar that has the tools available, including gadgets and an embeddable calendar.

If you want to code something yourself you'll probably want to look at [retrieving events](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#RetrievingEvents), [updating events](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#UpdatingEvents) and [creating events](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#CreatingEvents).